# How hard is it to fly a US-registered private jet over Cuba?

Tags: international, clearance, private-jets

I know that commercial airlines have airspace passage agreements that allow them to fly over Cuba, but what about private jets? Is it easy for a pilot of a US-registered private jet departing from Miami to get an overflight clearance from Cuba? What is the procedure?

I am specifically asking about an overflight, not a landing. In other words the pilot wants to fly over Cuba en route to some other destination in South America.